# How to group data from a bulk table based on a certain data's pattern?

Tags: sql, group-by, grouping, aggregate

I have a table with more then 14000 rows. The data inserted into the table from  a bulk operation.

The table looks like the following:

```
LineNumber Data
1          100000 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
2          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
3          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
4          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
5          100000 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 2
6          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
7          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
8          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
9          OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
10         100000 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 3
11         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
12         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
13         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
14         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
15         TOTAL                                         100.00 
16         111111 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
17         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
18         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
19         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
20         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
21         111111 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 2
22         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
23         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
24         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
25         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
26         TOTAL                                         100.00 
27         222222 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
28         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
29         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
30         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
31         OTHER RELATED DATA---------------------------------- 
32         222222 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 2
33         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
34         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
35         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------
36         OTHER RELATED DATA----------------------------------   
37         TOTAL                                         100.00  

and etc...
```

I want to create a temp table based on the above data, which will contain ONLY 3 rows for each file.
The table will have 3 columns, Start, End, BankID

Something like that:

```
Start    End    Data
1        15     100000 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
16       26     111111 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
27       37     222222 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
```

I have the following logic to create and populate the table:

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') is not null drop table #MyTempTable
create table #MyTempTable(
    Start int,
    End int,
    [Data] nvarchar(max)
)

insert into #MyTempTable(Start, End, [Data])
select 
    min(LineNumber),
    max(LineNumber),
    [Data]  
from Bulk_Table where [Data] like '%RUNNER222----BANK FILE%'
group by [Data]
```

However, when I select from my table, I have the following:

```
Start    End     Data
1        1       100000 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
15       15      100000 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 2
16       16      111111 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 3
26       26      111111 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 1
36       36      222222 BANK       RUNNER222----BANK FILE                  PAGE 2
```

Basically, what I'm looking for is for the temp table to have the same amount of records as amount of banks, in this case 3, and each row to have when batch starts, ends and which bank is a batch for.

What am I doing wrong? 
I'm grouping by the Data, containing the bank and getting the min and max of the line numbers

What is the right approach here?

Comment: I assume that you have a different page number in the data column for those rows (hence the multiple groups). Like `... PAGE 1` and `... PAGE 3`. It's kind of a hack, but maybe `group by left([data], 11)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just typed in the wrong page number

Comment: Ok, so doing the group by left trick should work. Not sure how I would approach secondarily at the moment. Perhaps another person has an idea. But that fix should get you to the goal line for now!

Comment: Thank's that helped a lot!

Comment: No problem! Here's a fiddle in case anyone wants to see: http://rextester.com/BHA35584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from the comments section to an Answer here. The problem is that the `[Data]` column contains a page number that is causing unique groups for each of the "BANK RUNNER" rows. My humble solution is to simply truncate the `Group By` using `Left`, thus cutting off the unique page numbers.

This can also be done with a number of other approaches, but this was a quick solution to change the original query:

```
insert into #MyTempTable(Start, End, [Data])
select 
    min(LineNumber),
    max(LineNumber),
    [Data]  
from Bulk_Table 
where [Data] like '%RUNNER222----BANK FILE%'
group by [Data]
```

to this:

```
insert into #MyTempTable([Start], [End], [Data])
select 
    min(LineNumber),
    max(LineNumber),
    left([Data], 11) as FirstElevenCharactersOfData
from Bulk_Table 
where [Data] like '%RUNNER222----BANK FILE%'
group by left([Data], 11)
```

Grouping by only the first few characters allows enough unique information to group on just the individual BANK values, and not the PAGE numbers.

RexTester example: http://rextester.com/BHA35584